# Get email and display name from alias in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, identity

is there any API in VSTS that's equivalent to IIdentityManagementService2 in TFS?  I used ReadIdentity(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731745(v=vs.120).aspx) to get the email address and display name of an account alias in TFS.  I am trying to do the same in VSTS, but I am not finding anything that can do similar things in its REST API or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.* libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get it via [Accounts and profiles](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/shared/accounts) in VSTS Rest API, the "Accounts" can get the accounts in the collection and the "Profiles" can get the information like Display Name, Email address for the member.

One thing you need to notice is that, to call "Accounts and profiles" API, you must use [OAuth2.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth) authentication.

> Q: Can I use basic auth with the profiles API?
>
> A: No, you must use OAuth.

Comment: I am trying to get the ID of an account using that account's email-alias. I looked through both Account and Profiles APIs, but could not find anything that does this.
Could you link the actual API page.